# Touch function in Postgres with PostGis

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, postgis, spatial

I have PostgreSQL installed with PostGis, I try to run the following:

```
SELECT N1.edname AS "Borders Royal Exchange A"
FROM eds_census2011 N1, eds_census2011 N2
WHERE Touch(N1.the_geom, N2.the_geom)
AND N2 = 'Royal Exchange A'
```

And I get an error (below) is there anything I have to add to Postgres or enable something?

> ```
> ERROR:  function touch(geometry, geometry) does not exist
> LINE 3: WHERE Touch(N1.the_geom, N2.the_geom)
>               ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: function touch(geometry, geometry) does not exist
> SQL state: 42883
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> Character: 96
> ```

Comment: `AND N2 = 'eds_census2011'` looks supicious, too (you cannot compare a table(alias) to a string constant)

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake there when typed, it shold be: Royal Exchange A. Thats not the error I was getting anyway

Comment: Do you actually have a column named `N2`, just like the table alias? Then you should table-qualify it! Else this is still syntactical nonsense: `AND N2 = 'Royal Exchange A'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run these two queries (in the same session you are trying the above query) to pin down the problem:

In which schema does the function `touch()` live?

```
SELECT p.proname, n.nspname
FROM   pg_proc p
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE  proname = 'touch';
```

What is the current schema [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) of my role:

```
SHOW search_path;
```

If the function exists, the schema must be in the current `search_path` so that Postgres can find it. How to adapt the `search_path`?
[How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)

BTW, I can't find a function `Touch()` in the function reference of the Postgis manual. There is one called [**ST_Touches()**](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Touches.html). Any chance you meant that one?

Be aware that this query has a cost of O(N²), since it calculates a value for every combination of any two qualifying rows in `eds_census2011`. If your condition `N2.edname = 'Royal Exchange A'` is selective enough, this won't be a problem.

Also, you may want to exclude rows joining themselves with an additional `WHERE` item like:

```
AND N1.pk_id <> N2.pk_id
```

#### Error after Update

Your updated query makes more sense:

```
SELECT N1.edname AS "Borders Royal Exchange A"
FROM   eds_census2011 N1, eds_census2011 N2
WHERE  ST_Touches(N1.the_geom, N2.the_geom)=1
AND    N2.edname = 'Royal Exchange A';
```

But `ST_Touches()` returns `boolean`, so the Where clause should just be:

```
WHERE  ST_Touches(N1.the_geom, N2.the_geom)
```

Comment: I made a few changes: `code`SELECT N1.edname AS "Borders Royal Exchange A"
FROM eds_census2011 N1, eds_census2011 N2
WHERE ST_Touches(N1.the_geom, N2.the_geom)=1
AND N2.edname = 'Royal Exchange A'`code`

Comment: but still get an error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 3: WHERE ST_Touches(N1.the_geom, N2.the_geom)=1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = integer
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 132

Comment: @AndreiIvanov: I added an answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

Got it - thanks to everyone, used the following:

```
SELECT N1.edname AS "Borders Royal Exchange A"
FROM eds_census2011 N1, eds_census2011 N2
WHERE ST_Touches(N1.the_geom, N2.the_geom)
AND N2.edname = 'Royal Exchange A'
```

Comment: Since my answer covers it, this one is redundant. A short comment would do.